# User password Reset without sending an email

Tags: 7

I know by default Drupal provides '*Forgot password*' option which allows user to enter their username/Email. If that's valid, sends a password reset link to their Email.

But I would like to do the same process without involving an email, which allows users to logged in immediately in one or two steps (by validating some checks).

How can I achieve that in Drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a module called [Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_reset). This is what I was looking for. I've tested this module and working great!.

> The password_reset module allows for passwords to be reset without involving e-mail addresses through the use of security questions. This module would typically be used on sites that do not require users to enter their e-mail addresses or prefer not having to deal with spam folder issues etc.